# Setup VPN to internet & DHCP Server for Subnet using 2 NIC not working

Tags: networking, vpn, dhcp

I have problems with my VPN attaching to the wrong NIC, or it just not working when two NIC are present.

My VoIP physical phone is being blocked by my service provider so i want to use an embedded system running Ubuntu 15.04/MATE with two ethernet ports to provide a VPN access to the internet on one ethernet port to the VoIP phone on the other.

I have eth0 connected to the internet, and eth1 is connected to the VoIP phone.
I have established a DHCP Server to provide service to the VoIP phone on eth1 as follows:

```
Contents of "/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf": 
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name "xu4.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.xu4.org, ns2.xu4.org;
# Set up our desired subnet:
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.2.101 192.168.1.254;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
        option routers 192.168.2.1;   
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
}
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
```

Also

```
Contents of "/etc/network/interfaces": 
# The uplink to the internet
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Assign a static IP for this DHCP server through eth1:
auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.2.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.2.255
        # gateway 192.168.2.1                       <- removed
        up route add -host 255.255.255.255 eth1
```

Also

```
Contents of "/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server": 
INTERFACES="eth1"
```

To check that the DHCP server is working on eth1

```
$ more /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
lease 192.168.2.101 {
    starts 4 2016/08/18 15:51:14;
    ends 4 2016/08/18 16:01:14;
    tstp 4 2016/08/18 16:01:14;
    cltt 4 2016/08/18 15:51:14;
    binding state active;
    next binding state free;
    rewind binding state free;
    hardware ethernet 7c:2f:80:9c:e0:cb;
    client-hostname "C530-IP";
}
```

So it appears the the DHCP is working and providing a lease to the VoIP phone

I then create a VPN connection and attach it to eth0 using the icon on the desktop

```
Network Icon->VPN Connections->Configure VPN->VPN->add
(setup gateway, username, password, use Point-to-point encryption, Name VPN1)
Network Icon->VPN Connections->Configure VPN->ethernet->eth0->Edit
(Automatically connect to VPN1 when using this connection, Automatic (DHCP))
```

Now when the system comes up, the default upstream connection appears as eth1 and not eth0. Trying to connect to the VPN fails.

The network maps is as follows:                                        UPDATED

```
$ route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     50     0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
173.255.160.5   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
173.255.160.129 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
173.255.160.136 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
```

And the ip addresses are:                                                UPDATED

```
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1e:06:30:3a:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.194/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 86365sec preferred_lft 86365sec
inet6 fe80::21e:6ff:fe30:3a92/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether de:66:fe:fe:85:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.2.1/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
link/ppp
inet 173.255.160.136 peer 173.255.160.129/32 scope global ppp0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ADDITIONAL
I have added the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf: net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 
I have also added the following iptables entries:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
$ sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i ppp0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth1 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
```

Questions?
a. Is there any way to check that eth0 traffic is actually going through ppp0? I presume because the eth0 destination is an address reelated to the vpn provider, this is the case?

b. The Voip picks up an ip of 192.168.2.101 and a network mask, but the gateway is set to 0.0.0.0. Also if I try and ping the voip there is no response. How do I provide a gateway to the Voip phone?

c. How can I check that the iptables are taking affect?

Thanks

Comment: For some reason your ppp0 interface is not coming up. Haven't played with VPNs in a while so maybe someone else can help. But one thing that does jump out is you're giving a default gateway to the phone `option routers 192.168.2.1;` yet you set your eth1 ip to 192.168.2.100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks meccooll for your help. It all works now.
In dhcpd.conf I added back the routers line and and also added the domain-name-servers because my phone was looking for a domain name to connect to.
I appreciate you help.
Lachlan

Answer (score 0):

Just reread your question, who's 192.168.2.1? If you don't want your traffic going that way why are you setting him up as a gateway on your eth1? Doesn't look like he can get you out to the internet. Since this gateway is set up as static it takes a priority over the gateway off of eth0 that you're getting via DHCP.

If for some reason you need that as a backup path try bumping up eth1 metric so it'll be your backup gateway think you need to add `up ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1 metric 150` to your eth1 config `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: A couple of things:

Comment: A couple of things: 1. Dont I have to provide a gateway for the Voip phone on the subnet provided by eth1? 2. If I do , is this automatically the address of this host on ethernet1 so that I make the address of iface eth1 to be 192.168.2.1 instead of calling it a gateway? 3. If I remove the gateway address of 192.168.2.1 which I thought was providing a gateway on the voip subnet, will the vpn now switch to the eth0 gateway of 192.168.1.1 prvided by the dhcp server in the router. I certainly dont want the vpn to look towards eth1 because the only thing on that subnet is the voip. Thanks

Comment: 1-yes you do, your current subnet on eth1 is 192.168.2.0-255 your voip is 192.168.2.101 and your eth1 is 192.168.2.100 yet you're telling your voip to send everything to 192.168.2.1 which doesn't exist!? If you want to route voip traffic through your PC tell your phone to send everything to PC set `option routers 192.168.2.100;` in your  `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

Comment: 2. No nothing is automatic it is whatever you want it to be. Voips default gateway must be the IP of your eth1, currently your phone is sending everything to 192.168.2.1, so either tell it to send everything to 192.168.2.100 (your current eth1 IP) as in #1, or change your eth1 IP to 192.168.2.1

Comment: 3 Yep,  setting gateway in `/etc/network/interfaces` tells YOUR COMPUTER where to send all of its traffic. Once it's removed the only other gateway the computer will know of is through DHCP on your eth0 so it'll have no option but to use that

Comment: ohh and you'd probably also want to enable IPv4 forwarding on your PC so it would actually forward traffic like a router to do that uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in your `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: I have done the suggestions you provided in 'dhcp.conf' and 'networking' entries as shown above, and also added the additional routing information. I have added three extra questions at the bottom of the post. It seems I am progressing must still missing a vital piece.

Comment: This is getting out of hand you need to break down your questions. No one will be able to follow this.  You can use `tracepath` to say google from your PC to check that the route is going through the VPN.  And even if the phone is not getting a gateway i don't see a reason why you can't ping it

Comment: I greatly appreciate your feedback. Is there a way to provide a gateway for the voip phone now that there is no 'router' entry in the dhcpd.conf file? Thanks

Comment: I didn't say to remove it just change it to your eth1 ip which is `192.168.2.100`